# How to use NSLog with data from a server

Tags: objective-c

Hi there I'm trying to do an NSLog but what I want to see is what it's inside of my dictionary like this.

NSLog(@"diccionario", diccionario);

And this warning appears:

Data argument not used by format string

The diccionario object contains data from a server so like I said I want to print in the console the info that diccionario contains, because is not printing anything.

Thanks.

Comment: It should be NSLog(@"dictionary is %@", diccionario);

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog(@"diccionario : %@", diccionario);
```

Should be the solution.

Comment: I'll try, thank you